# What is the meaning of double down

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of the word `double down`? As per the dictionary definition "strengthen one's commitment to a particular strategy or course of action, typically one that is potentially risky." Also, there is an example sentence for the word 'double down'.

Example sentence: `He decided to double down and escalate the war`.

But that does not clarify(at least for me) the usage of the word `double down`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The [wiktionary definition](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/double_down) seems clear enough to me:

> 1. (*gambling*) To double one's wager. In particular, it is the name of a specific doubling bet allowed in blackjack.
> 2. (*by extension, often followed by the preposition **on***) To double or significantly increase a risk, investment, or other commitment.

So you can use it:

- Literally, meaning to double one's bet in the game of blackjack
- By extension, when referring to any betting/gambling or investment decision (perhaps meaning "to *exactly double* one's bet/investment," or perhaps just meaning "to increase it")
- Metaphorically, when referring to any decision where someone has the opportunity to change their mind but they decide to keep going on their original path, particularly if they intensify or emphasize their decision.

Comment: It may be worth noting that, in Blackjack, when you double down, you're not only doubling your wager, but you're also restricting your options since you're only allowed one more card. This extends to the metaphor; generally when you double down on something, you're usually doing so at the irrevocable expense of something else.